# undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Following code fails to compile

```
#include <atomic>
#include <functional>

struct SetPair {
    uint64_t first;
    uint64_t second;
};

int main() {
    int N = 1024;


    void* MEM = nullptr;
    int t = posix_memalign(&MEM, 64, N * sizeof(std::atomic<SetPair>));
    auto V = new(MEM) std::atomic<SetPair>[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) V[i].store({0,0}, std::memory_order_relaxed);  


    free(MEM);

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation is terminated with the following message:

```
/tmp/ccLkjmPg.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4e): undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Code is compiled using the following flags:
`g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -I../include test.cpp`

If I change the type of atomics from SetPair to just uint64_t. It works fine.

Comment: Try adding `-march=native`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Can you explain a little bit more? As what is going wrong?

Comment: @letsBeePolite: You need to configure the compiler to target an architecture that can perform the required operation in hardware, otherwise it gets stubbed out.

Comment: @Check You won't have the guarantee that struct SetPair will be atomic. Only basic and primary primitives such as int, uint and other are guaranteed to be atomic.

Comment: seems you're missing `-latomic` on gcc's command line